# RadButton not causing postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a RadButton on a user control.   When I run the site in the debugger, and click the button, it doesn't even cause a postback, because the Page_Init event doesn't fire.    I have even set AutoPostBack="true" and CausesValidation="false" to bypass those possible explanations.

Here is my Radbutton code:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="ReturnButton" runat="server" Text="Return To Test" OnClick="ReturnButton_Click" 
 CausesValidation="false" Skin="Telerik" CssClass="rbClearButton" Width="175px" AutoPostBack="true" >  

<Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbPrevious" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"/> 
 </telerik:RadButton>
```

When I view source, here is is the HTML that is generated:

```
<a id="TestModuleDetails_ReturnButton" class="RadButton RadButton_Telerik rbSkinnedButton rbClearButton" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display:inline-block;width:175px;"><!-- 2011.3.1305.35 --><span class="rbPrimaryIcon rbPrevious" style="top:4px;left:4px;"></span><input class="rbDecorated rbPrimary" type="submit" name="TestModuleDetails$ReturnButton_input" id="TestModuleDetails_ReturnButton_input" value="Return To Test" style="width:100%;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:4px;" /><input id="TestModuleDetails_ReturnButton_ClientState" name="TestModuleDetails_ReturnButton_ClientState" type="hidden" /></a>
```

I don't see why it doesn't cause postback, anybody see what I'm missing?  I have posted this in the Telerik forums, and the Telerik people want me to send them a runnable code sample that reproduces the error.  I really hope I can avoid that headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think at 2 problems :

- I think you should have something like : href="javascript:void(0)"  in the balise A. because this stuff mean you want the link to do nothing ...
- second check in the javascript console if there is any error

Comment: Turned out the problem was a change I had made to the javascript, which introduces another question, but one that doesn't fit the scope of this heading.   Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

also test the control in a brand new empty page. if it works there, try recreating the current page from scratch.